# Is there any possibility to login Magento 2 front-end customer through Rest API

Tags: magento2, login, rest-api

I'M trying login Magento-2 front end customer through rest api but if browse api url through browser then only the customer logged in, and if excute that api through php script then the customer not logged in. is there any better way to log in front end magento-2 customer through rest API

Comment: yes, user  context Interface

Comment: im tying so many way but if excute that api through php script then the customer not logged in so please suggest me